SVG Icon Not Displaying in Light Mode with CSS
I have a html generated in this way.
<h2 class="mt-10 scroll-m-20 border-b pb-1 text-3xl font-semibold tracking-tight first:mt-0" id="know-your-life">
  <a aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" href="#know-your-life">
    <span class="icon icon-link"></span>
  </a>
  Know your life
</h2>

The icon displays correctly in dark mode, but it's not visible in light mode. Here is the HTML and CSS I'm using:
:where(h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6) {
  position: relative;
}

:where(h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6) span.icon.icon-link {
  display: none;
}

:where(h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6):hover span.icon.icon-link {
  display: inline;
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 16 16" version="1.1" width="16" height="16" aria-hidden="true"><path fill="%23000000" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M7.775 3.275a.75.75 0 001.06 1.06l1.25-1.25a2 2 0 112.83 2.83l-2.5 2.5a2 2 0 01-2.83 0 .75.75 0 00-1.06 1.06 3.5 3.5 0 004.95 0l2.5-2.5a3.5 3.5 0 00-4.95-4.95l-1.25 1.25zm-4.69 9.64a2 2 0 010-2.83l2.5-2.5a2 2 0 012.83 0 .75.75 0 001.06-1.06 3.5 3.5 0 00-4.95 0l-2.5 2.5a3.5 3.5 0 004.95 4.95l1.25-1.25a.75.75 0 00-1.06-1.06l-1.25 1.25a2 2 0 01-2.83 0z"></path></svg>');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: 0.8em;
  height: 0.8em;
  width: 0.8em;
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-right: 0.5em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Dark mode icon */
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  :where(h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6):hover span.icon.icon-link {
    filter: invert(1);
  }
}

In dark mode, the icon appears correctly with the intended color. However, in light mode, the icon is not visible at all. I suspect the issue is related to the color settings or the filter property, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

why the icon is not displaying in light mode and how to fix it?

I think it's just always white because of your @media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) CSS rule. Changing to light mode with your button in the top right corner will probably not change your prefers-color-scheme setting. You can just check if the svg is in the DOM in the developer console of your browser.

On hover i don't see any change on the dom.

Why should the DOM change on hover? But you can just see in the source code of the page if your svg is there. If it's there, then it's just white (due to your CSS rule filter: invert(1);), so you can't see it on a white background.

The issue is filter: invert(1); part.
Firstly try to remove :hover part from :where(h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6) span.icon.icon-link to see your icon always and then try to hover on that - it changes colour only on hover. With invert(1) you change it from black to white even in light mode (try commenting out inverting part).
Also see this thread if you're using older Chrome: CSS prefers-color-scheme works on Firefox but not on Chrome issue

yes on hover it was being changed to black to white, in light mode
